# tkinter bindo to a button or change the command of a bind

Tags: python, tkinter

Ive made a game where at the end of the game, I change the command that is called by the button.

I was wondering if there was a way to link the `bind` to the button rather than the command, or if I could change the command called by the `bind`.

Here is my code for the button:

```
# create the button
self.but = Button(win, text="Submit", command=lambda: self.check_input(win))
self.but.grid(row=10, column=2, columnspan=3, sticky="NEWS")
win.bind("<enter>", self.check_input(win))

# change the button command
self.but["command"] = lambda: self.next(win, self.game_init)
self.but["text"] = "PLAY AGAIN!"
```

Comment: If you bind the key to `lambda e: self.but.invoke()`, the key will do whatever the Button does, even if that changes later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your function does not use `Event` passed by tkinter when a widget is bind-ed, then it is fairly simple:

```
def check_input(self,win,event=None):
    ....
    ....

self.but = Button(win, text="Submit", command=lambda: self.check_input(win))
....
win.bind("<enter>", lambda e: self.check_input(win,e))
```

Though an easier and dynamic way to always follow the buttons command is(like jasonharper said) but you cannot use `e` at all, even if triggered by the given event:

```
win.bind("<enter>", lambda e: self.but.invoke())
```

An example to account for using same function with `bind` and `command` of a button:

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def func(win,e=None):
    if e is not None:
        print(f'Triggered by the hitting the {e.keysym} key')
    else:
        print('Triggered by the pressing button')


but = Button(root,text='Click me',command=lambda: func(root))
but.pack()

root.bind('<Return>',lambda e: func(root,e))

root.mainloop()
```

---

Also a good time to mention, your event is wrong, either you meant `'<Return>'`(enter key) or `'<Enter>'`(when you enter the bounds of a widget with cursor)